# How to count frequencies of columns in python3 dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello guys I have a dataframe with columns that go like this. 
cols:

- WhiteRating(int)
- BlackRating(int)
- NewGameNinePtLead(str, determines if position is a "missedMate", "lostBigLead", "useless")
- AverageRating
- Rating_Group: **X** grouped rating
- length_of_checkmate(the amount of moves to checkmate, int): this is my **y** value

Inside of this data frame, every row is a single observation that has all of these column properties. 
My task is to calculate variable **P** and then Regress p against x, regress p against y and finally p against (x and y)
P= (the number of moves having a value of y and lost)/(total # of moves having value y)

My problem is finding **P** for my groups. I am not sure how to approach this in a pythonic way I can manually loop and count all but even then I am not sure on how to approach it, and with the size of my data frame this could take a very long

```
WhiteR,BlackR,EMV,MovePlayedValue,NewGame,NinePtLead,AverageRating,Rating_Group,length_of_checkmate
1880.0,1865.0,27.0,27.0,1,useless,1875,1800,0
1880.0,1865.0,22.0,21.0,1,useless,1875,1800,0
1865.0,1880.0,25.0,25.0,1,useless,1875,1800,0
1880.0,1865.0,24.0,19.0,1,useless,1875,1800,0
1865.0,1880.0,22.0,22.0,1,useless,1875,1800,0
1880.0,1865.0,27.0,27.0,1,bigLeadLost,1875,1800,2
```

Comment: Can you include a small sample of your dataframe? `df.head(10)`

Comment: just added it in. Thank you for the reminder!

Comment: More than one row preferably...

Comment: how do you define 'moves having a value of y'?

Comment: that is determined based on the length_of_checkmate column, it has int values all referencing how many moves to checkmate

Comment: My dataframe is very large, with tons of strings that I need for other analyses so I doing df.head(10) will give me a nice little essay to remove from. Is the provided okay?

Comment: Thank you for adding the code into the code block @rahlf23 wasn't sure how to do it correctly in this.

Comment: so in your sample data, the 'number of moves having a value of y and lost' is 5, and 'total number of moves having value y' is 6?

Comment: Oh no, there is only 1 for y currently and that is the last line with 2 at the end(not interested any rows with a value of 0 all values greater than 0 I care about). This means that at this position there is a mate in two moves potentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood your question correctly: you want frequency of the types of y that resulted in a lose (non-zero types), divide by the total moves of y (types of y):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = {'WhiteR': [1880.0,1880.0,1865.0,1880.0,1865.0,1880.0],\
  'BlackR': [1865.0,1865.0,1880.0,1865.0,1880.0,1865.0],\
  'EMV': [27.0,22.0,25.0,24.0,22.0,27.0,],\
  'MovePlayedValue':[27.0,21.0,25.0,19.0,22.0,27.0,],\
  'NewGame':[1,1,1,1,1,1],\
  'NinePtLead':['useless','useless','useless','useless','useless','bigLeadLost'],\
  'AverageRating':[1875,1875,1875,1875,1875,1875],\
  'Rating_Group':[1800,1800,1800,1800,1800,1800,],\
  'length_of_checkmate':[0,0,0,0,0,2]}


df = pd.DataFrame(df)
status=df['length_of_checkmate'].value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 
'length_of_checkmate', 'length_of_checkmate': 'Freq.'})

df1 = pd.merge(df, status, on = ('length_of_checkmate'))
df1['P']= (df1['Freq.']/df1['length_of_checkmate']).replace(np.inf, 0)

#then proceed to 'Regress p against x, regress p against y and finally p against (x and y)'
```

Comment: A couple of questions about your code, I have not tested it yet I would just like to understand a couple of things first. 1) what does reset_index() exactly do, I have seen this used lots of times but sadly can't understand it 2) the .replace(np.inf,0) that is numpy.inf as in infinity. Why that statement? Thank you very much for working on this!

Comment: 1) rest_index() is for renaming your columns  2) .replace(np.inf,0) is for dividing by the 0 rows, you can ignore the rows = 0 in your later steps, the steps here so far are only for calculating P.  also i put the P column back to your dataframe for your later steps since you will be using X

Comment: This is brilliant!!!!!!! Thank you so much, I am just a bit confused how you are able to do value_counts().reset_index().rename(). That part confuses because doesn't the length of the dataframe have to be a constant throughout the entire dataframe?

Comment: Forgot to ask one more thing this P that is generated is for all moves. How would this be defined for just the Group_Rating. So to correlate those two together